# How does "your new password must differ at least n characters from the previous" work when only hash codes are stored?

Tags: password, password-management, hash, password-policy

I am wondering how the password policy "your new password must differ at least *n* characters from your old password" works.

My understanding is that the OS never actually *stores* the old passwords *themselves*, but their *hash codes* instead. And there is no way of knowing in how many characters the two strings differ if you have *only their hash codes*.

Am I right in the guess that it can work only if the `passwd` program *asks you explicitly* at the same time also *for your old password*?

And is the consequence that if a *root* user changes someone else's password, the "number of different characters" policy simply **cannot** be applied here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such policies are usually implemented by applying them when asking for the old password.

Another option would be to brute-force the old one. When you input your new one, a modern computer has no problem to brute-force all passwords which differ by 2 characters from the new one. As far as I know this is not used in the normal authentication in typical linux distributions but possible some PAM modules implement this.

The usual approach for root changing passwords is to assume that the superuser know's what he's doing. The passwd program does not ask for the old password and allows you to override rules like a minimum length at your own risk.

Answer (score 4):

You're right. *If* passwords are stored as hash, there's absolutely no way for the operating systems to know how the new password differs from the old one.

The policy check is done from the tool and it works since the tool asks you also for the old password and then checks the differences against a set of policy rules.

Comment: Obviously, you need to trust the operating system. But this is another question :)

Answer (score 1):

> And is the consequence that if a root user changes someone else's password, the "number of different characters" policy simply cannot be applied here?

The administrative user can usually manipulate the password database directly, so effectively all password policies can be ignored by that user.
For instance root can provide a hashed password (with `usermod -p`) that will be set verbatim, or edit `/etc/shadow` and set the hashed password there.

That is yet another reason why administrative users  should be held to a higher standard and train themselves to use a password generator when assigning passwords for users.

Comment: Thanks for that point of view, too! Unfortunately I cannot accept more than one answer :)